# numpy where operation on 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array 'A' of size 571x24 and I am trying to find the index of zeros in it so I do:

```
>>>A.shape
(571L, 24L)

import numpy as np
z1 = np.where(A==0)
```

z1 is a tuple with following size:

```
>>> len(z1)
2
>>> len(z1[0])
29
>>> len(z1[1])
29
```

I was hoping to create a z1 of same size as A. How do I achieve that?

Edit: I want to create array z1 of booleans for presence of zero in A such that:

```
>>>z1.shape
    (571L, 24L)
```

Comment: "I was hoping to create a z1 of same size as A." - what would you expect that `z1` to mean? You seem to be looking for a data representation other than what `np.where` provides. What data representation are you looking for?

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to find the indices of where zeros occur in the array?

Comment: isn't that just `z1 = A==0` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just check this with the equality operator in python with numpy. Example:

```
>>> A = np.array([[0,2,2,1],[2,0,0,3]])
>>> A == 0
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

`np.where()` does something else, see [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Although, it is possible to achieve this with `np.where()` using broadcasting. See documentation.

```
>>> np.where(A == 0, True, False)
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.array([[0,3,4,5],[9,4,0,4],[1,2,3,4]])
ix = np.in1d(myarray.ravel(), 0).reshape(myarray.shape)
```

Output of ix:

```
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```